# Debian 10 - Oracle JDK not showing up in update-alternatives

Tags: linux, debian, java, openjdk

Inside a Debian 10 VM I have first installed OpenJDK 11, and it was all OK.
Then I have installed Oracle JDK 13 according to instructions posted in [Computing for geeks](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-oracle-java-13-on-ubuntu-debian/), that means `wget`-ting the .deb file and install it with `dpkg -i`.

I have got no errors, but when running `update-alternatives --config java` I get this answer:

```
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

Why? How can I switch from one JDK to the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The alternatives are handled by pre- and post-install hooks. There seems to be no hook included in the package you downloaded, but you can easily add an alternative manually:

```
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /path/to/OracleJDKs/java 2
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /path/to/OracleJDKs/javac 2
```

Afterwards you should be able to select a Java version by running `update-alternatives --config java` and `update-alternatives --config javac`.

However, the `java-package` [package](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/java-package) always provided an easy way to install Oracle JDK on a Debian system. Since I have not used it for quiet a while I can not say if it is still compatible with current Java releases.